# Jquery result caching in MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, call

I am working on a mvc3 application where I have a 3 controller methods returning 3 json results. I use a jquery ajax call to get 3 results and append then to 3 divs in a page header partial view. I have 50 pages in my application and all pages call header partial view internally. When each page call partial view jquery gets data from 3 controllers and binds to a div. Its very heavy operation and I am looking for some caching mechanism here. Could some one help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Below code is for all $.get, $.ajax globally declared.
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        //========= Or ================//

        //Below code is for particulat jquery ajax.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your_URL', type: 'Get',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    });
```